# Wordpress - trying to create a function with the loop but not see the posts

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to create a simple list of posts from a certain category and I wanted to put that function in my functions.php so I could just call the short code.

I get the list I want however, I also get the full posts below the list... ? I dont want the posts.

(Also wondering how to get these posts in reverse Chronological order)...

Here is my function:

```
function getVolArchives() {
    query_posts('category_name=volunteerspotlights&showposts=12');
        echo '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        echo '<li style="width: 50%; float: left;"><a href="'. get_permalink() . '"><div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">' . get_the_title() . '</div><div class="archiveName">' . get_the_date('F') . '</div></a></li>';
    endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
}

add_shortcode('getVolArchives', 'getVolArchives');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the sorting you can find all the acceptable parameters for query_posts() here in the [class reference for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) which query_posts uses - **order** and **orderby** specifically, will handle your sorting needs.

Also, I'm not sure if this will address your issue with the full posts, but in my experience it was best to build a string with these functions and return the string rather than echo the content out directly.

I'm a little rusty regarding WP at the moment, so someone else may be better able to conjure up a better fix/example:

```
function getVolArchives() {
    query_posts('category_name=volunteerspotlights&showposts=12&orderby=date&order=DESC');

    $return_string = '<ul style="list-style: none;">';

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $return_string .= '<li style="width: 50%; float: left;"><a href="'. get_permalink() . '"><div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">' . get_the_title() . '</div><div class="archiveName">' . get_the_date('F') . '</div></a></li>';
    endwhile;

    $return_string = '</ul>';

    return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode('getVolArchives', 'getVolArchives');
```